# how to setup and mirror two visual screen (a) touch 3.5 touch screen in general 40 pin connector and (b) hdmi 1 over TV?

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, pi-4

I have new 4GB Rasberry Pi 4. I would like to mirror a [touch screen,3.5 inch TFT LCD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XCKSYRH)  over 40 point connector and HDMI 1 over TV. I could not connect both and mirror together. Sorry I new to Rasberry pi.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev thank you for the response. Actually I have case with the touch screen like above in picture for the small screen and a tv like above to mirror - which has hdmi.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this page](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/LCD-Modules) to see if your LCD is supported by `fbtft`. If it is, find out its device name and try to set it up (yours looks like `tinylcd35`):

```
sudo modprobe fbtft_device name=tinylcd35

# check if you have /dev/fb1. If so, try using it, e.g.

# map a login console
con2fbmap 1 1

# run X windows (remove xorg.conf if it refers to /dev/fb0)
FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb1 startx

# play a video
sudo SDL_VIDEODRIVER=fbcon SDL_FBDEV=/dev/fb1 mplayer -vo sdl -framedrop test.mpg

# view a picture
fbi -d /dev/fb1 -T 1 -noverbose -a test.jpg
```

Framebuffer mirroring is described in the [wiki](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/Framebuffer-use#framebuffer-mirroring), and involves installing a DMA driver and running `fbcp` process while the mirroring is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems that as of November, 2019, this cannot be done.

It can definitely multi-display using the same protocol/driver, however it can't do it if you are using DSI + HDMI.

The issue is that the underlying boot code enables a framebuffer to HDMI or a framebuffer for DSI, but not both.

There are TFT screens that actually have HDMI / mini HDMI input so you can have one of those as well as the TV

Comment: thank you for the answer - I tried to understand and use this but too complex and not sure works- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=199531